# Updated woocommerce, all old orders now missing from woocommerce back-end

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I recently updated the woocommerce plugin on a wordpress ecommerce store that I manage, however, previously the theme being used on the site had been developed from a template & once the update of woocommerce completed, the front-end of the site broke.

As a result I reverted back to the old version of woocommerce as a temporary fix. The problem is that now in the back-end in the orders tab, none of the orders from before the update are being shown - even though it states that there are over 4000.

I assume that this is something to do with the DB?

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe [this](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201887113-woocommerce-2-2-4-only-completed-orders-missing) might contain the solution because it's kind of a similair problem. And if you can't get the answer here, you might wan't to ask the [woocommerce support](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us).

Comment: You are on the right path for sure. The "order status" was previous controlled by a custom taxonomy. Now it is controlled by "post_status".